# Android run expensive process when ui thread is free

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

Is there a way to detect when the UI thread is free? I have a layout that is very expensive to inflate. I've improved the layout as much as I can (using ViewStubs, etc.). The view for this layout will not be used till later when a user scrolls halfway through. But to prevent jankiness, I wish to detect when UI thread is completely free (ie. user isn't interacting/scrolling), so that I can inflate this layout during this time and save it for later. This way, when the user gets to the part with the expensive view, no jankiness will be observed.

Any tips on how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: see `MessageQueue#addIdleHandler`